# Cloud Storage Default Bucket was not created

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

On 2015-01-08 I created a new project with id (open-311) from https://console.developers.google.com and there is no default bucket.

Will the bucket show up if I wait?

Should I create a bucket with the same name as the project?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Go to your App Engine Developer console:

https://appengine.google.com/dashboard?&app_id=s~your-app-id

Then to Application Settings > Cloud Integration

and turn on the GCS option.

Comment: just a general note - there is a method called "get_default_bucket_make" or similar (in python). If you call it and nothing is displayed then your bucket does not yet exist and doing the above can/will fix that.

Comment: Thank you.
The multiple number of "dashboards"/"consoles" for App Engine and Google Cloud projects is very confusing.
I hope they ~Google~ get things consolidated sooner rather than later.

Comment: Agreed.  I get lost in the maze many times with Google's poor UIs, be it App Engine, Adwords, Analytics, etc.

Answer (score 1):

2016 update: the option to create a default cloud storage bucket is now available in the new console (https://console.developers.google.com).

Just go to App Engine > Settings

The option is under "Default Cloud Storage Bucket".